# PHP Array select result from other array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a sql table with some category, i get them in a array.. all fine but when i try to get data from another table foreach category, always return me for first category selected.

This is my code:

```
$gameguidecategoryes = array();
$gameguides = array();  


$dbselectgameguidecategoryes = new DB_MSSQL;
$dbselectgameguidecategoryes->Database=$newweb_db;
$dbselectgameguidecategoryes->query("Select GameGuideCatNr,GameGuideCatName_$languageid as GameGuideCatName,GameGuideCatImage from GameGuide_Category where GameGuideCatVisible = 1 order by GameGuideCatOrder asc");
for($i=0;$i < $dbselectgameguidecategoryes->num_rows();++$i) { 
    if ($dbselectgameguidecategoryes->next_record()){
        $GameGuideCatNr = $dbselectgameguidecategoryes->f('GameGuideCatNr');
        $GameGuideCatName = $dbselectgameguidecategoryes->f('GameGuideCatName');
        $GameGuideCatImage = $dbselectgameguidecategoryes->f('GameGuideCatImage');
    }
    $gameguidecategoryes_temp = array(
        'ggcname' => $GameGuideCatName,
        'ggcimg' => $GameGuideCatImage,
    );

    $gameguidecategoryes[$i] = $gameguidecategoryes_temp;

    $dbselectgameguide = new DB_MSSQL;
    $dbselectgameguide->Database=$newweb_db;
    $dbselectgameguide->query("Select GameGuideID,GameGuideName_$languageid as GameGuideName from GameGuide_Content where GameGuideCat = $GameGuideCatNr and GameGuideVisible = 1 order by GameGuideOrder asc");

    for($ii=0;$ii < $dbselectgameguide->num_rows();++$ii) {
        if ($dbselectgameguide->next_record()){
            $GameGuideID = $dbselectgameguide->f('GameGuideID');
            $GameGuideName = $dbselectgameguide->f('GameGuideName');
        }
        $gameguides_temp = array(
            'ggid' => $GameGuideID,
            'ggn' => $GameGuideName,
        );

        $gameguides[$ii] = $gameguides_temp;
    }
}
```

Why $gameguides return data only from first category?

Thank you

Comment: Not 100% sue on this. Few things come to mind. Step 1 stick in a few debug statements with printing out the contents of $gameguidecategoryes and $i as well as $ii. Step 2. isn't it $i++ or $i=$i+1 Step 3. I think you should bind the category_id in the query. Step 4. don't use num_rows() - or if you do stick it in a temp variable as it has to count the rows each time. Instead a something like while($result = $dbselectgameguide->next_record()) might be better. Step 5 - put the query into a variable that you can echo out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second loop keeps getting trashed by the first loop. e.g. Consider what happens:

1. You fetch your categories, and (let's pretend) there's 4 of them.
2. You store some information in `$gameguidecategoryes[0]`
3. You run the second query, get some content for category #0, say, 3 records
4. That gets stored in `$gameguides[0]`, `[1]`, `[2]`
5. Your outer loop ticks again, and you start on `categoryes[1]`
6. The inner loop ticks again, you get 4 records, and now you're storing them into the **SAME** again: `$gameguides[0]`, `[1]`, `[2]`, `[3]`, etc...
7. You've now trashed the data you fetched in the first loop, and will

do so for every category you fetch.

This code is very inefficient. You should learn how to use `JOIN`s, and fetch into a single structure, e.g.

```
SELECT category.id, category.name, ...., content.id, content.name
FROM categories
LEFT JOIN content ON categories.id = content.category_id
ORDER BY ...
```

and then something like

```
$data = array();
while($row = fetch row from db) {
    if (!isset($data[$row['category.id']]) {
       $data[$row['category.id']] = array(
           'name' => $row['category.name'],
           'content' => array()
       );
    }
    $data[$row['category.id']]['content'][] = array(
          ... save content data here
    );
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your idea.

Answer (score 1):

Better work on clean code

```
$gameguidecategoryes = $gameguides = $gameguidescategoryids = array();  

$dbselectgameguidecategoryes = new DB_MSSQL;
$dbselectgameguidecategoryes->Database=$newweb_db;
$dbselectgameguidecategoryes->query("Select GameGuideCatNr,GameGuideCatName_$languageid as GameGuideCatName,GameGuideCatImage from GameGuide_Category where GameGuideCatVisible = 1 order by GameGuideCatOrder asc");

while ($dbselectgameguidecategoryes->next_record()) {
    $gameguidescategoryids[] = $dbselectgameguidecategoryes->f('GameGuideCatNr');

    $gameguidecategoryes[] = array(
        'ggcname' => $dbselectgameguidecategoryes->f('GameGuideCatName'),
        'ggcimg' => $dbselectgameguidecategoryes->f('GameGuideCatImage'),
    );
}

if (count($gameguidescategoryids)) {
    $dbselectgameguide = new DB_MSSQL;
    $dbselectgameguide->Database=$newweb_db;
    $dbselectgameguide->query("Select GameGuideID,GameGuideName_$languageid as GameGuideName from GameGuide_Content where GameGuideCat IN (".implode(',', $gameguidescategoryids).") and GameGuideVisible = 1 order by GameGuideOrder asc");

    while ($dbselectgameguide->next_record()){
        $gameguides[] = array(
            'ggid' => $dbselectgameguide->f('GameGuideID'),
            'ggn' => $dbselectgameguide->f('GameGuideName'),
        );
    }
}
```